How to I resize a table output from an R chunk?
I have the following R chunk in a .Rmd file:
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
texreg(list(reg1a, reg1b, reg1c, reg1d),
       custom.coef.names = custom_coef_names,
       custom.coef.map = custom_coef_map,
       label = "table:main")
```

I would like to shrink it by 80% so it would fit on the page. I've tried the following:
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
cat("\\begin{table}[ht]\\centering\\scalebox{0.8}{")
texreg(list(reg1a, reg1b, reg1c, reg1d),
       custom.coef.names = custom_coef_names,
       custom.coef.map = custom_coef_map,
       label = "table:main")
cat("}\\end{table}")
```

I keep getting the following error when I try to knit the document:
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Is there anything I'm missing and need to do get the table output to shrink?

Don't scale elements which contain text. Instead either choose a suitable font size or change the layout of your table,

I used in fontsize = "small" in texreg() and it worked! Thanks.
